# Flutter - FocusNodes and Navigator causing TextField to lose its decoration

Tags: flutter

I came across a very weird Flutter bug, that maybe someone has some insight on.

Flutter doesn't have currently have a great way to automatically move from TextField to Textfield in a form.  The recommended solution is to create a FocusNode for each Textfield and then when the user finishes editing, programatically select the next FocusNode.

The seemed to work fine, however it also causes some very strange visual glitches if your form is not on the first route in an app (which more often then not the case)

On the second route, as soon as you tap a TextField, the decoration will blink momentarily and then disappear, however the curser will remain.  You can keep selecting TextFields and you will eventually end up with a cursor on every field.  The field still function correctly, so this is purely a visual glitch.

[TextField with more than one curser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niNtq.png)

The problem seems to be strongly coupled to the Navigator.  If you create a screen on the first route with custom FocusNodes, it behaves fine.  Conversely if you don't use FocusNodes on the second screen, its also fine.  Its only when you combine both of these that the issue arises.

Here is a simple app that exhibits this problem.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(TestApp());
}

class TestApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: TestScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () => _pushSecondScreen(context),
            child: Text('Push to a new screen')
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }

  void _pushSecondScreen(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) =>     SecondTest()));
  }
}

class SecondTest extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Second Screen'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        children: List<Widget>.generate(10, (i) => _buildTextField(i)),
      ),
   );
 }

 Widget _buildTextField(int index) {
    // The custom focus node is thrown in here for example, but in a real world app,
    // a reference to the node would be kept so the app can manage focus between the nodes
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
      child: TextField(
        focusNode: FocusNode(),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Field $index',
          filled: true,
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0))
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I posted to code to duplicate this issue in this gist:
https://gist.github.com/bkayfitz-cara/8da2afd964c7f4417435e9df49b4cd9e

Comment: [This article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-flutter-textfields-f0e676aaab7a) may be helpful, especially the part about initializing outside of the build method.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar experience using FocusNode on multiple text fields with a cursor on every field.  Then I realized I needed to instantiate a separate FocusNode for each text field and the problem went away.